# VBA Word: Update Find Format with current selection

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I'd like the have **Find** in Word automatically populate its formatting based on the text I've selected. I.e. if I have my cursor on text that's ***bold and italic***, I'd like to be able to find all text that match this format without having to actually go through the manual process of selecting these formats in the **Format** -> **Font** window in the **Find** dialog.

With some help of Word's macro recording function, I've come to a working solution:

```
Sub FindFormat()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
        .Size = Selection.Font.Size
        .Bold = Selection.Font.Bold
        .Italic = Selection.Font.Italic
        .Underline = Selection.Font.Underline
        .StrikeThrough = Selection.Font.StrikeThrough
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = Selection.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough
        .Hidden = Selection.Font.Hidden
        .SmallCaps = Selection.Font.SmallCaps
        .AllCaps = Selection.Font.AllCaps
        .Color = Selection.Font.Color
        .Superscript = Selection.Font.Superscript
        .Subscript = Selection.Font.Subscript
    End With
End Sub
```

I could technically use it and be done. The problem is it's not that intuitive, as it's hard to see the formatting it has applied, the comma delimited list under the **Find** field is never ending and gets cuts off the window with ellipses, rendering it impossible to read all formatting applied:

[image: Microsoft Word Find]

So, to cut to the chase, how do I have VBA only change the formatting options that is different than neutral, and cut the rest, i.e. **No Underline, Font color: Auto**, etc. should not be changed in **Find**'s **Format** (leaving its checkbox in a neutral state)?

In addition, how do I call the **Find** dialog to open with all these settings without any actual find execution (so I can manually add text or change any formatting as desired, for example)?

With appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, I'd use IF statements like those that follow.

```
.Size = Selection.Font.Size
If Selection.Font.Bold = True Then .Bold = Selection.Font.Bold
If Selection.Font.Italic = True Then .Italic = Selection.Font.Italic
If Selection.Font.Underline <> wdUnderlineNone Then .Underline = Selection.Font.Underline
If Selection.Font.StrikeThrough = True Then .StrikeThrough = Selection.Font.StrikeThrough
If Selection.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough = True Then .DoubleStrikeThrough = Selection.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough
If Selection.Font.Hidden = True Then .Hidden = Selection.Font.Hidden
If Selection.Font.SmallCaps = True Then .SmallCaps = Selection.Font.SmallCaps
If Selection.Font.AllCaps = True Then .AllCaps = Selection.Font.AllCaps
If Selection.Font.ColorIndex <> wdAuto Then .ColorIndex = Selection.Font.ColorIndex
If Selection.Font.Superscript = True Then .Superscript = Selection.Font.Superscript
If Selection.Font.Subscript = True Then .Subscript = Selection.Font.Subscript
```

And so on for any other values you want to keep track of. (Note that I used ColorIndex rather than Color. I'm using Word 2010, and this is the correct property for me.)

I'm not sure how to do the second part. Theoretically you'd set the Find argument of the wdEditFind dialog box, but in actuality that only seems to take a string as its value.

One other thing; if you want to cycle through possibilities, using Find is likely the way to go. However, if you're trying to get a list of all text with a particular formatting, an easier way is to right-click the selected text and then choose Styles > Select All Text With Similar Formatting. Then you can just copy and paste into another file. May or may not be relevant to your needs, but it's a handy trick from some cases.